# Read memory of Java applet running inside browser

Tags: java, memory

I use C# to program and use ReadProcessMemory to read the memory of other processes running on the system. However, I'm unsure how to read the memory of a java applet that is running inside a browser? Has anyone tackled this before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 6u10 the default Java PlugIn runs outside of the browser process(es). The process should be readily identifiable as a Java executable with PlugIn classes added to the bootstrap class path.

Answer (score 0):

If the JVM is executing as part of the browser process, I suspect you won't be able to do this easily. The closest you'll be able to get is to measure the browser memory consumption.

However you could measure the memory consumption of the standalone [applet viewer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/appletviewer.html) whilst running your applet, and then perhaps derive the applet memory consumption from that.